# Grails JasperService: how do I pass parameters to a report?

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I have a simple Jasper report and a Grails app that uses *jasper* plugin to generate a report. The report has a parameter with a default value. Say, its name is `user_id` When I print the report, the default value is used and the result is ok.

Now I wish to be able to pass my own parameter value to the report. Here is the code I use to get my report:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperExportFormat
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.jasper.JasperReportDef
...
{   
    // def user_id = 1
    def reportDef = new JasperReportDef(name:'iResume.jasper', fileFormat:JasperExportFormat.DOCX_FORMAT)
    def file = jasperService.generateReport(reportDef).toByteArray()
}
```

How do I pass a param, for example `user_id` into the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to do it with this code:

```
    params.put("_file", "iResume.jasper")
    params.put("_format", "DOCX")
    params.put("user_id", 1)

    println params

    def reportDef = jasperService.buildReportDefinition(params, request.getLocale(), [])
    def file = jasperService.generateReport(reportDef).toByteArray()
```

I took this from the Jasper taglib and the controller code. This is kind of Voodoo programming cause I don't know what the last param `[]` is for, but it works. Will be grateful if anyone can clarify what's going on here.

Comment: Looks like the last parameter is the model map http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-jasper/tags/RELEASE_1_1_1/grails-app/services/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/jasper/JasperService.groovy